# where saves data openerp in offline

Tags: odoo

What is the limit and where 
is the data stored when browser is offline in openerp?

Answer (score 1):

That is not completely correct. In general, OpenERP doesn't store any data offline. But modules can implement this type of feature. Specifically, the Point of Sale module has this implemented, using HTML5 [LocalStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

In `addons/point_of_sale/static/src/js/db.js` you can read:

> PosLS is a LocalStorage based implementation of the point of sale database, it performs better for few products, but does not scale beyond 500 products.

Comment: POS keeps continue data entry when there is no connection and it stores the data in local-storage of browser.

HTML5 allows Browser to store data locally within the user's browser.

For the limit of data storage in browser is depends on capacity of localstorage of particular browser.

Like 5MB per domain in Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome, and Opera, 10MB per storage area in Internet Explorer.

So it can store the data according to storage capacity of browser.

Comment: "backbone-0.5.3.js" library is used to store data in local-storage when server is not running (off-line mode).

Comment: Good answer Priyanka to your own question :P