# How POS Module store data in OpenERP 7.0 in term of technical

Tags: html, odoo

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775773/where-saves-data-openerp-in-offline)

It's pretty clear that the transaction of POS while the connection btw client and host is lost. the data will be store in HTML5 LocalStorage.

Here a question.

1 What about the master data for example the items, item's information, promotions where it will be stored?

Cheers